# Why is my application closing after starting Activity from custom View?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view

I am working on a simple game in Android studio and I'm calling GameOver activity, with Try Again button form the Game Activity (which is just named MainActivity). It is called when the main character collides with one of the monsters. What is my problem is that when I try to finish by `((Activity)getContext()).finish();` My application closes instead of starting the new activity. This is the method that starts it:

```
public void isCharacterDead(){
    for (Monster item : monsters) {
        if (characters.get(0).deadCollision.contains(item.collision.centerX(), item.collision.centerY())) {
            player.stop();
            long gameOverDelayEnd = (System.nanoTime()/1000000)+1000;
            long gameOverDelayStart = System.nanoTime()/1000000;

            while(gameOverDelayStart < gameOverDelayEnd){
                gameOverDelayStart = System.nanoTime()/1000000;

                }
            characters.remove(0);

            Intent gameOver = new Intent(getContext(),GameOver.class);
            gameOver.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
            getContext().startActivity(gameOver);

            }
    }
}
```

And my GameOver Activity is:

```
public class GameOver extends Activity {
    private Button tryAgain;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //removing the title from the screen in order to have empty screen
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);

        tryAgain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tryagain);
        tryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent game = new Intent(GameOver.this, MainActivity.class);
                GameOver.this.finish();

                startActivity(game);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now if i don't use `((Activity)getContext()).finish();`, it is starting the GameOver activity and when Try Again is clicked I move to new instance of the Game Activity(MainActivity). But it drops the performance on each new start via the Try Again button in GameOver. I suppose it is due to starting the new game Activity over the last one without finishing it. Any suggestion on what to do to avoid this? There's nothing inside the android monitor as an exception (My GPU monitor is disabled also).

Comment: why do you use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and where is your code written? how does the method getContext() work?

Comment: isCharacterDead() is within the custom View. It is called after the update for each frame for the sprite positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to swap these two lines:

```
((Activity)getContext()).finish();
getContext().startActivity(gameOver);
```

And do not forget to `break` the `for` loop when you start the activity

Edit:

After editing your questions adding your complete code it is now clear the reason 
of your problem:

You are calling the method `upd` from the thread you create,`upd` in turn calls the method `isCharacterDead` that is finishing the activity, but accessing any UI elements is not allowed from any thread other than the UI thread.

you can use `runOnUiThread` to fix it:

replace the lines that starts activity and stop the current with the following:

```
((Activity)getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
              Intent gameOver = new Intent(getContext(),GameOver.class);
              gameOver.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              getContext().startActivity(gameOver);
              ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
        }
 });
```

Comment: I swapped them but it's still the same - the app closes itself with no message or anything. If I don't finish the activity every new start from GameOver the performance corrupts on the Emulator, on the real device it even closes the application on the 4th use. If it's more clear, MainActivity starts GameScreen view in which I call the GameOver activity as shown in the question.

Comment: If it Matters my Manifest looks like this:
 `<activity android:name=".GameActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameOver"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

            ></activity>`

Comment: Can you post logcat so that we can help you better

Comment: Here is the logcat - [CLICK](https://pastebin.com/9z7JjWvm) This is after i swapped the code as in your answer. The GameOver activity is not displaeyd at all. If I don't finish the game activity from the custom view, Game Over screen is displayed.

Comment: And [THIS](https://pastebin.com/y7f1kzXE) is when i don't have the `((Activity)getContext()).finish();` code line. After the 5th tap on Try Again button in Game Over activity i get this error.

Comment: This is because your app gets out of memory and this has no relation to the main question

Comment: I think the context that starts the activity has something wrong, can you please post your complete code so that I can check the method getContext

Comment: I've added in edit the View class, I tried experimenting by creating MainActivity reference in GameOver activity and finish it there but it still closes the app. Got some exception with locking the canvas in the thread class tho. Maybe i should start the intent and finish the main activity with 2 separate threads?

Comment: I have edited the answer, please mark it as correct if it helps

Comment: I've tried replacing the code in `isCharacterDead()` as in the edited answer, but i still get the same freeze which leads to closing the application. Or maybe i should implement it in another method? Should i call it in `upd()` or in `surfaceDestroyed()` ?

Comment: It should be replaced in 'isCharachterDead()`, anyway check that you terminate the thread correctly and use Logcat to check what is going on, but this solution should work anyway

Comment: Thank you! Actually it is working now but I had to save the context in a private variable Context and not just call it with getContext(); Anyways now i'm getting null pointer exception because the thread is running but my SurfaceView is no longer available. I'm new to programming and have no idea how to terminate it even in the code but I will research it. Your answer is correct for my question.